# rounding .5 down in java

Tags: java, rounding

How can you implement a rounding function which will round all numbers as usual except 0.5 or any odd multiple of it down to the nearest integer?

For example:

- `2.899` is to be rounded up to `3.0`
- `2.332`  is to be rounded down to `2.0`
- `2.5` is also to be rounded down to `2.0` (and NOT `3.0`)

Comment: You mean rounded _down_. (You said up twice)

Comment: I assume you mean "round half down" as per http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_down

Comment: What about negative numbers? Are you rounding towards zero (-2.5 rounds to -2.0) or down? (-2.5 rounds to -3.0)

Comment: I assume you want 3.5 to round down to 3.0 also, and not to 4.0 (as "round-half-to-even" would do)?  Just making sure I understand what you mean by "odd multiple".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `BigDecimal` as follows:

```
public static double roundHalfDown(double d) {
    return new BigDecimal(d).setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN)
                            .doubleValue();
}
```

**Example:**

```
for (double d : new double[] { 2.889, 2.332, 2.5 })
    System.out.printf("%.2f  ->  %.2f%n", d, roundHalfDown(d));
```

**Output:**

```
2.89  ->  3.00
2.33  ->  2.00
2.50  ->  2.00
```

Answer (score 4):

You can determine the fractional part fairly easily with the help of Math.floor(), then round from there based on the fractional part:

```
public static double roundHalfDown(double d) {
    double i = Math.floor(d); // integer portion
    double f = d - i; // fractional portion
    // round integer portion based on fractional portion
    return f <= 0.5 ? i : i + 1D;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You must use BigDecimal an MathContext look here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/MathContext.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#ROUND_HALF_DOWN

Summary of Rounding Operations Under Different Rounding Modes

Using these classes the round works has follows

```
Input HALF_DOWN
5.5     5   
2.5     2   
1.6     2   
1.1     1   
1.0     1   
-1.0    -1  
-1.1    -1  
-1.6    -2  
-2.5    -2  
-5.5    -5
```

Comment: The last two results conflict with http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html.  Have you tested it?  (Did this change from Java 6 to Java 8?)

Comment: The `BigDecimal.html` page that you link to says that -2.5 and -5.5 should "round down", but their definition of "round down" means toward 0.  (See the definition of `ROUND_DOWN` on the same page.)  So I believe the last two result should be `-2` and `-5`, even in Java 6, unless you have an implementation that's doing the wrong thing.

Comment: Sorry was m¡y mistake. Thanks ajb